# What do these Google search operators/attributes mean?

Tags: google-chrome, search-engine, google-search

In the Google Chrome search engines, there is the default engine URL defined as: `{google:baseURL}search?{google:RLZ}{google:acceptedSuggestion}{google:originalQueryForSuggestion}sourceid=chrome&ie={inputEncoding}&q=%s.`

I understand what it does and I know how to modify/customize the search engines, but now I would like to know whether I could customize my own search engines (I have set up several for Google alone) further if I would know what these operators/attributes mean. Could you please explain me the meaning of the following:

- `{google:baseURL}` (or is that just google.com?)
- `{google:RLZ}`
- `{google:acceptedSuggestion}`
- `{google:originalQueryForSuggestion}`

Answer (score 2):

`{google:baseURL}` is defined in the source as `http://www.google.com/`. `{google:RLZ}` has to do with [RLZ](http://code.google.com/p/rlz/). The other two seem to have to do with what you type in the address bar and what you actually pick for Chrome to search on.

Comment: What does "*what you type in the address bar and what you actually pick for Chrome*" mean? Also, folks are quoting your answer on http://stackoverflow.com/a/18219627/632951 ... Might help if you could provide some sources/justification/evidence/etc.

Comment: @Pacerier: It was buried so deep within the Chromium source that I can't replicate the discovery path anymore.